# Efficient and clean way of growing a tokenizer function in Python

Tags: python, performance, tokenize

I have a library that does some "translation" and uses the awesome `tokenize.generate_tokens()` function to do so.

And it is pretty fast and I have things working correctly. But when translating, I've found that the function keeps growing with new tokens that I want to translate and the `if` and `elif` conditions start to pop all over. I also keep a few variables outside the generator that keeps track of "last keyword seen" and similar.

A good example of this is the actual Python documentation one seen here (at the bottom): http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.untokenize

Every time I add a new thing I need to translate this function grows a couple of conditionals. I don't think that having a function with so many conditionals is the way to or the proper way to pave the ground to grow.

Furthermore, I feel that the tokenizer consumes a lot of irrelevant lines that do not contain any of the keywords I am translating.

So 2 questions:

1. How can I avoid adding more and more conditional statements that will make this translation function easy/clean to keep growing (without a performance hit)?
2. How can I make it efficient for all the irrelevant lines I am not interested in?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question but part of it seems that you want to avoid a long if-elif-elif chain.  If you are testing for equality to a constant you can store them in a dictionary: `switch = {'FOO': somefunc, ... }`.   And then do `switch['FOO'](args)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dict dispatcher. For example, the code you linked to might look like this:

```
def process_number(result,tokval):
    if '.' in tokval:
        result.extend([
            (NAME, 'Decimal'),
            (OP, '('),
            (STRING, repr(tokval)),
            (OP, ')')
            ])
def process_default(result,tokval):
    result.append((toknum, tokval))

dispatcher={NUMBER: process_number, }
for toknum, tokval, _, _, _  in g:
    dispatcher.get(toknum,process_default)(result,tokval)
```

Instead of adding more `if`-blocks, you add key-value pairs to `dispatcher`.

This may be more efficient than evaluating a long list of `if-else` conditionals, since dict lookup is `O(1)`, but it does require a function call. You'll have to benchmark to see how this compares to many `if-else` blocks.

I think its main advantage is that it keeps code organized in small(er), comprehensible units.